# Cleanest Way to Select Every Second Element in a Loop?

Tags: loop

What's the quickest and easiest way to select every second element in the loop?

At the moment I'm using this strange method:

```
<ul>
<?php $k = 1; ?>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li class="<?php if($k%2 == 0) echo 'last'; ?>"><?php the_content(); ?></li>
<?php $k++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Can't use nth-child since IE doesn't support it and CSS3 PIE isn't playing nice with my site at the moment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't consider that strange :). WordPress uses a similar method to apply the 'alternate' class to every other row in the tables on the admin page, something like:

```
<ul>
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
     <?php $class = (empty($class) ? 'class="alternate"' : '');?>
     <li <?php echo $class; ?> ><?php the_content(); ?></li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Good to know. Thank you! Sorry I can't vote up your answer, I haven't got 15+ reputation at the moment. You've got my vote though.

Comment: You can always 'accept' answers (clicking the tick to the left) :). I'd encourage you to do so - it clears your question off the 'unanswered' pile and means others can quickly identify a 'correct' answer.

Comment: Ahh, cheers! I didn't even see that there.